# How to write primary key in django 2.0.2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

the below code is working only for index page but it's not working for my DetailView. Please help me to fix (Using Django 2.0.2)

The below is my class for view:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Album


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = "newboston/index.html"
   context_object_name = "all_album"

       def get_queryset(self):
          return Album.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'newboston/detail.html'
```

The below is my urls.py under my application.

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: What is your question? And what does it have to do with primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should refer to the primary key using **pk** in the **urls.py** file ...

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Further details are in the documentation [near the end of the page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/), or search for "**polls/urls.py**".